# Checking for version updates in two large lists of names and versions

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, optimization, package-managers

I have two very large lists of packages with their versions, and I'm attempting to compare them to determine if there are any that are of a higher version. An example of my data:

```
listOne = ['autoconf-2.69-4',  'b43-fwcutter-019-1', 'binutils-2.28.0-3']
listTwo = ['autoconf-2.69-4', 'automake-1.16-1',  'binutils-2.29.0-1']
```

Now I need to find the packages that are a higher version than listOne. In the above example, only binutils matches the criteria.

These lists are ordered, but each list has packages unique to only itself, shared packages of the same version, as well as packages of the same name, but only a different version. Those are what I'm looking for. Order of the final list is needed, and the packages must maintain their current naming scheme.

My current code to do this is as follows:

```
listOne = ['autoconf-2.69-4',  'b43-fwcutter-019-1', 'binutils-2.28.0-3']
listTwo = ['autoconf-2.69-4', 'automake-1.16-1',  'binutils-2.29.0-1']

uniqPackages = sorted(list(set(listTwoPackages) - set(listOnePackages)))

for package in uniqPackages:
    for packageFull in listOne:
        if packageFull.rsplit("-", 2)[0] == package.rsplit("-", 2)[0]:
            versionValue = compareVersions(packageFull.rsplit("-", 2)[1] + "-" + packageFull.rsplit("-", 2)[2], \
                package.rsplit("-", 2)[1] + "-" + package.rsplit("-", 2)[2])
            if versionValue:
                print(package.rsplit("-", 2)[0] + "-" + package.rsplit("-", 2)[1] + "-" + package.rsplit("-", 2)[2])
```

The function `compareVersions` is a custom function that will return True if the second version is newer than the first value. There are some that are of a lower version, which I do not want.

This code is kind of cludgy, and rather slow as my lists are very huge. Is there anyway I can speed up this comparison process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it wrong:
for every package in one list, you are iterating over all the second. 
Complexity is `M x N` (M, N = len(first), len(second)).

Given that packages are ordered, you can use iterations like in merging algorithms (makes step on first OR second arrays, which ever is smaller, printing result as it goes). So, complexity will be linear (`M + N`), not square.

Just a hint for comparison - I would recommend take a look into standard library `distutils.version.LooseVersion`

It can be instantiated from any string, and then be compared:

```
LooseVersion('19.1-alpha') < LooseVersion('19.3')
LooseVersion('19.10-alpha') > LooseVersion('19.3')
```

[Some docs over the internet](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/distutils.version.LooseVersion-class.html)

As for other little optimizations, note that there are a lot of repeating same-value calculations, like `.rsplit` calls, better introduce a variable and reuse it.

Here's how I would implement it:

```
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

def compare_versions(a, b):
    return LooseVersion(a) < LooseVersion(b)

i, j = 0, 0
M, N = len(first_packages), len(second_packages)

while i < M and j < N:
    package_f, version_f, minor_f = first_packages[i].rsplit('-', 2)
    package_s, version_s, minor_s = second_packages[j].rsplit('-', 2)

    if package_f == package_s:
        if compare_versions(
            '-'.join((version_f, minor_f)),
            '-'.join((version_s, minor_s))
        ):
            print(second_packages[j])
        i += 1
        j += 1
    else:
        if package_f < package_s:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1
```

Another implementation using `heapq` module, it may be faster:

```
import heapq
last = ''
name = lambda p: p.rsplit('-', 2)[0]
version = lambda p: '-'.join(p.rsplit('-', 2)[-2:])
for pckg in heapq.merge(first_packages, second_packages, key=name):
    if last and name(last) == name(pckg) and compareVersions(
        version(last), version(pckg)
    ):
        print(pckg)
    else:
        last = pckg
```

Comment: I really like this approach, but for reasons unbeknownst to me, this actually takes a little over twice as long. Under my current code, it takes 0m46.053s and under your code it takes 2m0.250s... The idea of a sort however is vastly more appealing than my nested loops.

Comment: I can't find any reason why it can be slower... That's probably because of different `compareVersions` ? LooseVersion handle a lot of cases, so not the simplest one instantiation and comparison... Or it can be because of `uniquePackages` is relatively small...